# Quickblox - Appcelerator Titanium integration - Chat

Tags: quickblox

Is it possible to integrate QuickBlox chat in Appcelerator Titanium. Looks like we may use REST API to integrate other objects not Chat object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for other objects instead of chat you can use CustomObjects REST API

Comment: Give me any example or hint for how it possible with titanium.

I have downloaded example from "https://github.com/QuickBlox/SimpleSample-users-titanium" but i get Error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)"

Comment: https://github.com/QuickBlox/SimpleSample-users-titanium - works for me, check please